# Sutton & Barto: Why expected square of the importance-sampling-scaled return is for policy b?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto

From "Reinforcement Learning: An introduction (2nd ed.)" by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto, on page 107 and 108:

> We can verify that the variance of the importance-sampling scaled
> returns is infinite in this last example. The variance of a random
> variable X  is the expected value of the deviation from its mean X¯:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}[X] \doteq \mathbb{E} \Big[ (X - \bar{X})^2\Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ X^2 - 2X\bar{X} + \bar{X}^2 \Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ X^2\Big] - \bar{X}^2
\end{align}

> If the mean of the random variable is finite (as in the example),
> having an infinite variance means that the expectation of the square
> of the random variable is infinite. Thus, we need only show that the
> expected square of the importance-sampling scaled return is infinite:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\_b \Bigg[(\prod_{t=0}^{T-1} \frac{\pi(A_t|S_t)}{b(A_t|S_t)}G_0 )^2\Bigg]
\end{align}

Question is following: why we calculate expected return for policy $b$ instead of $\pi$? If we approximate returns for $\pi$ using importance sampling aren't we supposed to calculate $\mathbb{E}\_\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why we calculate expected return for policy $b$ instead of $\pi$?

The expected return for policy $b$ is not being calculated here:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_b \Bigg[(\prod_{t=0}^{T-1} \frac{\pi(A_t|S_t)}{b(A_t|S_t)}G_0 )^2\Bigg]
\end{align}

This expression is part of the variance of the importance-sampled expected return for $\pi$, given that your observations of $G_0$ are all made following $b$. The expectation of this value is shown as expected following policy $b$, because that is what you directly observe.

If you were instead observing returns from following the policy $\pi$, you wouldn't have the problem with possible unbound variance when trying to convert it.

The proof is showing a problem inherent to the conversion maths. The importance sampling **is** still approximating $\mathbb{E}_{\pi} \Big[G_0\Big]$, but the proof needs to look at the conversion in detail to show the possibility of infinite variance.